# Convert std_logic_vector to enum type in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I want to create verilog testbench for the vhdl designs but my vhdl design source contains some enum type cannot accept by Vivado's  mixed language boundary [Ref](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/ism_r_mixed_lang_boundary_mapping_rules.htm). So I create a VHDL wrapper to convert enum type to std_logic_vector type or convert std_logic_vector to enum type. There are some elegant way to converting enum type to std_logic_vector [Convert enum type to std_logic_vector VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254941/convert-enum-type-to-std-logic-vector-vhdl). But How to converting std_logic_vector to enum type in VHDL?

Comment: If you dont want to use an integer conversion (as per @Renaud's answer), they you will need to manually define all the encodings for your enum for the encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are mentioning Vivado I guess you are more interested in synthesis semantics than simulation semantics. I will thus assume that your `std_logic_vector` objects carry information that can be considered as the binary representation of integers, and that you are not interested in `std_logic` values other than `'0'` and `'1'`.

To convert `std_logic_vector` values to an enumerated type you will first need a large enough enumerated type. So, if your vectors are `N` bits long you will need a `2^N` values enumerated type, for instance, if `N=16`:

```
type s2e_t is (s2e0, s2e1,... , s2e65535);
```

(lot of typing but as you asked for it...) Then, you can simply convert your vector values to non-negative integer values and pick the corresponding enumerated type value with the `val` type attribute (dual of the `pos` attribute):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
type s2e_t is (s2e0, s2e1,... , s2e65535);
signal e: s2e_t;
signal s: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
...
e <= s2e_t'val(to_integer(unsigned(s));
```