# Type to integer

Tags: vhdl

I have the following (does not synthesize):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

library work;
use work.bus_pkg;

entity gpio_controller is
    generic (
        gpio_count : natural range 1 to natural'high
    );
    port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        gpio : inout std_logic_vector(gpio_count - 1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of gpio_controller is
    type inout_type is (
        DISABLED,
        OUTPUT,
        WEAK_PULLUP,
        WEAK_PULLDOWN);
    constant inout_type_bitlength : natural := integer(ceil(log2(real(inout_type'high))));
begin
    gpio <= (others => 'Z');
end architecture;
```

What I want is to determine `inout_type_bitlength`, the minimum amount of bits required to enumerate inout_type, which should be 2 in my case (since 2 bits are required to enumerate 4 states).

Now the approach I chose does not work, but is there a way to make this work?

Bonus question, can I somehow create something that will automatically map the integers 0 to n to a state, no matter how many states there are?

Comment: "the minimum amount of bits required to enumerate 4": `powershell -command "[math]::log(4) / [math]::log(2)"`

Comment: I was (not too) surprised to see the touted AI search on Stackoverflow did a poor job compared to  googling. This is a duplicate of [Convert enum type to std_logic_vector VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254941/convert-enum-type-to-std-logic-vector-vhdl) which is the first Google hit (for me, and I don't log in). The same on DuckDuckGo both with the search term "vhdl enumeration to binary" The search involved finding seearch terms that approached the problem. (I was curious if the down vote was from lack of research effort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the POS attribute to convert type values to int. Therefore, we get:

```
inout_type'pos(inout_type'high)
```

To get the integer value of the highest element in the type. Putting it together:

```
constant inout_type_bitlength : natural := integer(ceil(log2(real(inout_type'pos(inout_type'high)))));
```

For the bonus question: once again, it is the pos attribute:

```
inout_type'pos(WEAK_PULLUP)
```

Gives 2 in this instance.